# Not able to use new model with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, controller

I have 2 models in my application ( Using rails 3.2.5)

1) User(From devise)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :encryptable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me

  # attr_accessible :title, :body
  has_many :profiles
end
```

2) Profiles.

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  attr_accessible :description, :name, :product, :image, :price
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
  validates_presence_of :name, :product, :image, :price
end
```

There are many profiles of one user . 
GOAL : I want to display only the profiles related to each user , when they login.

By reading rails document we can create a new profile for a user by (Code below), But this gives an error
"undefined method `Profile' for nil:NilClass"

Can somebody help me to define my controller's index,show,new,edit,create,update ,destroy or show me one and i can do it for all.

```
def new
  @profile = @user.Profile.new

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @profile }
  end
end
```

Comment: The model is defined as Profile and User and so it should be : def new
    @profile = @User.Profile.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @profile }
    end
  end
But it still gives error.undefined method `Profile' for nil:NilClass

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving this error because the `@user` is not initialized and is equal to nil so it has no method named `profile`, you should be using `current_user` helper of devise to get the current user `@user = current_user`.

Comment: def new
    @user = current_user
    @profile = @user.Profile.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @profile }
    end
  end

Still get the error " undefined method `Profile' for #<User:0x007fb03608ef60>

Comment: please help by changing the code accordingly . did i define it right

Comment: Still i get undefined method `profile' for #<User:0x007fb036f0fcb0>
def new
    @user = current_user
    @profile = @user.profile.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @profile }
    end
  end

Comment: are you sure you have a column named `user_id` in the profiles table?

Comment: in console i get 
Started GET "/profiles/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-12-31 13:02:14 -0500
Processing by ProfilesController#new as HTML
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 3 LIMIT 1
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `profile' for #<User:0x007fb036f0fcb0>):
  app/controllers/profiles_controller.rb:34:in `new'

Comment: I am not able to get what wrong i have done, maybe in future when i generate a model i should not use capital, the query gets generated but i still get the error. Please help and i will apprecite it as i need to put my basics right.

Comment: As @Khaled mentioned, there's no `profile` method on User, use `profiles` -> `@profile = current_user.profiles.build`

Comment: i get unknown attribute: user_id

Comment: @khaled i don't have user_id in the profiles table. Does not rails handle this automatically when i create a relationship in my model. do i have to create the user_id manually , by a migration?

Comment: you must have a `user_id`, create it by a migration.

Comment: @Khaled Thanks , it worked, the error is gone and i able to create the  profiles. I created user_id in profiles table via migration, but user_id always remains blank in the database, when i add a new profile and that is why the profiles don't show up in index. How do i fix this? .. Thanks in advance for your help . this

Comment: when i manually added user_id into the database , the profiles showed up. How do i make sure that user_id is populated when new profile is created ?

Comment: @khaled how do i make sure that user_id is populated when new profile is created. with current_user.profiles.build , the user_id is not updating .

Comment: it should set the user_id as you are using `current_user.profiles.build`, try creating a profile for a user in your console and see what's the output.

Comment: strange when i do it from console it gets updated but not from my controller.
1.9.3p327 :012 > my_profile.save
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (122.3ms)  INSERT INTO "profiles" ("created_at", "description", "image", "name", "price", "product", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", Tue, 01 Jan 2013 19:36:29 UTC +00:00], ["description", "test"], ["image", nil], ["name", "vin"], ["price", #<BigDecimal:7ff6cd5364b8,'0.1E3',9(18)>], ["product", "bedding"], ["updated_at", Tue, 01 Jan 2013 19:36:29 UTC +00:00], ["user_id", 4]]
   (1.5ms)  COMMIT

Comment: my profile model is:class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  
  attr_accessible :description, :name, :product, :image, :price , :user_id
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
  validates_presence_of :name, :product,  :price
end

Comment: my controller method has  @profile = current_user.profiles.build

Comment: @khaled , please help me debug this , i am not able to find why my user_id is not getting updated , i am using postgresql.

Comment: @khaled any suggestion to debug this issue